# c++11 way of returning an array of unknown number of elements

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, compile-time

I would like to implement this function (or a similar one, see the requirements below) in C++11:

```
template<typename... ARGS>
constexpr std::array<const typename std::common_type<ARGS...>::type, sizeof...(ARGS)> asConstArray(ARGS&&... args)
{
    return {std::forward<ARGS>(args)...};
}

struct DataBinding {
    static constexpr auto getRawBindings()
    // HERE          ^- C++14, deduced to std::array<const BindingInfo, 2> in this case
    {
        return asConstArray(
            DEF_BINDING(int, stateProp, stateParam), //BindingInfo constexpr object
            DEF_BINDING(float, areaProp, areaParam)  //BindingInfo constexpr object
            //(...)
        );
    }
};
```

As you see I would like to introduce a macro-based interface (it is necessary, it does a lot of other Qt related magic).

DEF_BINDING returns a constexpr object of an user-defined struct (`BindingInfo` - it contains a few `const char*` and `size_t` members, it can be replaced with any struct or template that can contain the same).

I don't want to force the programmer to count the bindings manually because it would be inconvenient. The solution above is the closest I could figure out, but I would like to solve the followings in C++11:

1. Needs to return an array of elements (array like, using `std::array` is
   not a must-have)
2. Must be compile time
3. The items must be defined only once (do not want to enumerate the array elements twice)
4. Must be header-only (static constexpr member defined in
   the cpp file cannot work, non-ODR regulated use can work)
5. The array-size must be auto-deduced

The solution can use any kind of C++11 magic. I hope we can figure out something :)

**UPDATE**: In the original post I forgot to mention a really important fact: getRawBindings is inside a struct.

Comment: It isn't clear what the actual problem is. You have C++14 code that you want to port to C++11, or something else?

Comment: Yes, my post starts with the question: "I would like to implement this function (or a similar one, see the requirements below) in C++11"

Comment: I am just wondering, since your constexpr has no argument, why is it not possible to instantiate the array directly as a constant ? (Using a macro to get the programmer input)

Comment: Or just use variadic template to get the list of bindings. From there you can use sizeof... to count the number of arguments and thus do not need auto when defining the return type.

Comment: @LaurentJospin Because of req. 4: Must be header-only (static constexpr member defined in the cpp file cannot work, non-ODR regulated use can work). I modify the post to emphasize it.

Comment: @LaurentJospin About the variadic template: I tried, but couldn't figure out a way to do it without enumerating the elements twice, pls. see req. 3: The items must be defined only once (do not want to enumerate the array elements twice)

Comment: You can use a typed variadic template (e.g., template<const BindingInfo... dims>). From there you need to have the user enter them once and from there you can extend the template to create your array.

There might still be something I am missing, maybe you should provide more details on how the users will actually use your interface. (Do they call a given macro multiple time, or do they have to enter a list in the constexpr code ?).

Comment: Using objects of classes/structs in the template argument list is C++20 AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trailing return type should do the job:

```
struct DataBinding {
    static constexpr auto getRawBindings()
    -> decltype(
        asConstArray(
            DEF_BINDING(int, stateProp, stateParam), //BindingInfo constexpr object
            DEF_BINDING(float, areaProp, areaParam)  //BindingInfo constexpr object
            //(...)
        )
    )
    {
        return asConstArray(
            DEF_BINDING(int, stateProp, stateParam), //BindingInfo constexpr object
            DEF_BINDING(float, areaProp, areaParam)  //BindingInfo constexpr object
            //(...)
        );
    }
};
```

To avoid the repetition, MACRO might help:

```
#define RETURN(Expr) decltype(Expr) { return Expr; }
```

and then

```
struct DataBinding {
    static constexpr auto getRawBindings()
    -> RETURN(
        asConstArray(
            DEF_BINDING(int, stateProp, stateParam), //BindingInfo constexpr object
            DEF_BINDING(float, areaProp, areaParam)  //BindingInfo constexpr object
            //(...)
        )
    )
};
```

Comment: Ah, just add another layer of macro magic :) It works, I modified a bit:
`#define DEF_BINDINGS(...) static constexpr auto getRawBindings() -> decltype(asConstArray(__VA_ARGS__)) { return asConstArray(__VA_ARGS__); }`, so one can write: `DEF_BINDINGS(DEF_BINDING(QString, state, AdvancedAirwayState)/*...*/)`

Answer (score 3):

How about using *trailing return type*?

```
#include <array>

template<typename... ARGS>
constexpr std::array<const typename std::common_type<ARGS...>::type, sizeof...(ARGS)> 
asConstArray(ARGS&&... args)
{
    return {std::forward<ARGS>(args)...};
}

struct DataBinding {
    template<typename... BINDINGS>
    static constexpr auto getRawBindings(BINDINGS&&... bindings)
    -> decltype(asConstArray(std::declval<BINDINGS>()...))
    // ^^^ trailing return type
    {
        return asConstArray(std::forward<BINDINGS>(bindings)...);
    }
};
```

Then you can call `getRawBindings()` like this:

```
constexpr auto raw_bingdings = DataBinding::getRawBindings(
                                 DEF_BINDING(int, stateProp, stateParam),
                                 DEF_BINDING(float, areaProp, areaParam)
                                 // ...
                               );
```

Comment: The idea is great, however the actual enumeration of the bindings would be outside the class in this case :( So in the outside world I want to use DataBinding::getRawBindings without enumerating the bindings there, like DataBinding::getRawBindings().

Comment: The usage of your idea looks like: constexpr auto raw_bingdings = DataBinding::getRawBindings( DEF_BINDING(int, stateProp, stateParam), DEF_BINDING(float, areaProp, areaParam) // ... ); 
Instead of this one could simply write constexpr auto raw_bindings = asConstArray( DEF_BINDING(int, stateProp, stateParam), DEF_BINDING(float, areaProp, areaParam) //(...));, so unfortunately it does not solve the issue :(

Comment: @Broothy. I understand what you mean, you can define `static constexpr BindingInfo data[] = {...}` inside `DataBinding`, and get its size through `sizeof(data)`, and then use `std::index_sequence` to unfold its elements to passed to `asConstArray`. However, there is no `index_sequence` in C++11, you need to make your own wheels. something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/b61WoEKE7).

Comment: I cannot use `static constexpr BindingInfo data[] = {...}` as a member then unfolding it as Req. 4: Must be header-only (static constexpr member defined in the cpp file cannot work, non-ODR regulated use can work) :(

Comment: constexpr variable can be declared and instanciated in the header in c++11. inline variables (introduced in c++17), are meant to declare and instance non constant variables in headers.

Comment: @LaurentJospin If one declares and instantiates a static constexpr member and use it in a function that is called from the outside world (e.g. in the real getRawBindings function), then the static constexpr member is affected by the ODR rule and need to be defined: "The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer."